# Docker Container Logs

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We are running [Century Link's Watchtower](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower) container. This allows us to have a watch a docker registry and download new images when they are created. When watchtower finds a new image it runs `docker rmi` which deletes the old container. With that the old logs go with it.

Is there a way without using a logging service to retain the logs when docker does it's clean up?

Comment: Are you sure the logs are gone?  You can't do `docker logs -f <container_id>` because the container is gone, but the log files themselves should still be somewhere like `/var/log/containers` with the container ID appended to the log nam.

Comment: Yes after the clean-up the folder with the old `container_id` is removed completely

Comment: Is [Logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) something that you could use? _Logspout is a log router for Docker containers that runs inside Docker. It attaches to all containers on a host, then routes their logs wherever you want. It also has an extensible module system._

Answer (score 1):

You can retain your logs by either logging to shared data volume :

Say you have logs of container in /apps/logs location

```
 docker volume create logs
 docker run -v logs:/apps/logs <image>
```

Or you can directly log onto host directory

`docker run -v /apps/logs:/apps/logs <image>`

So, by these methods you can retain your logs even after old containers and images are deleted.